# Focus method not working on my gridview but does not color the textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, textbox, focus

I have an gridview where my Headerrow is enabled and under my headerow i have textboxes that users enter value into and click insert to insert into the database.

The User Wanted:
1) the focus method be at the first textbox of the gridview
2) depending on the focus method change the color of the text box to light gray

**was successful in creating a jquery that would allow me to change the color of the text box **

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="carmel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('INPUT[type="text"]').focus(function() {
            $(this).addClass("focus");
        });
        $('INPUT[type="text"]').blur(function() {
            $(this).removeClass("focus");
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.focus {
border: 2px solid black;
background-color: #D6D6D6;
}
</style>

</head>
```

**and to set the focus on to the first textbox in the gridview i am doing this**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox txtproductline = (TextBox)GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("TextBox6");
            txtproductline.Focus();

        }
```

the focus works but it is not coloring the textbox to light gray, when i tab the next textbox gets colored to gray am i doing something wrong here??

**i also tried**

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {

              e.Row.FindControl("TextBox6").Focus();


            }
```

the above code too sets the focus where i want it to be but the jquery is not working

When the user first loads the pages 
[image]

when the user hits tab on the keyboard
[image]

**it works perfectly when i run the application from Visual Studio but when hosted on the webserver its acting funny**
**Any suggestions/fix would greatly be appreciated, have a good rest of your day, Happy Coding**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Jquery code defines what happens when a control get or loses focus AFTER the page is already loaded (draw) and your textbox already has focus.
 You probably can add in Page_Load or where you set focus on the first line, something like txtproductline.CssClass="focus"

Comment: perfect appreciate it bud

Comment: when the user clicks the scroll at the bottom the focus is lost and after that when he hits tab the focus starts from the first textbox, how would i still keep the focus even though the horizontal scroll is clicked??

Comment: Probably you will need to handle scroll event from jquery, and reassign focus on that event. something lilke $(window).scroll(function(){ $("#txtProductLine").focus();});..